# Why doesn't a spaces only value for a field that has the blank: false constraint fail validation

Tags: unit-testing, grails

I have a field in a domain class that I applied the blank: false constraint to and I write a unit test to verify that a spaces only string for the field doesn't pass the validation, but the test fails:

```
void 'test name cannot be blank'() {

    when:
    domain.name = ' '

    then:
    !domain.validate(['name'])
    domain.errors['name'].code == 'blank'
}
```

I this the `ConditionNotSatisfiedError` error on the line `!domain.validate(['name'])`: ConditionNotSatisfiedError

This is my domain object:

```
class Thing {

    String name

    static constraints = {
        name nullable: false, blank: false, size: 1..20
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your constraints for the domain object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't indicate what version of Grails you are using and that will likely be relevant.  The project at https://github.com/jeffbrown/selenablank demonstrates how this works in 3.3.3.

https://github.com/jeffbrown/selenablank/blob/master/grails-app/domain/selenablank/Thing.groovy

```
package selenablank

class Thing {
    String name

    static constraints = {
        name nullable: false, blank: false, size: 1..20
    }
}
```

https://github.com/jeffbrown/selenablank/blob/master/src/test/groovy/selenablank/ThingSpec.groovy

```
package selenablank

import grails.testing.gorm.DomainUnitTest
import spock.lang.Specification

class ThingSpec extends Specification implements DomainUnitTest<Thing> {

    void 'test name cannot be blank'() {

        when:
        domain.name = ' '

        then:
        !domain.validate(['name'])
        domain.errors['name'].code == 'blank'
    }
}
```